# How to structure a website built upon own API in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a small TV Show library in laravel. I want to include an API as well for possible future expansion. When I started I had 2 controllers for what should have been a single controller: API controller and the web frontend controller. They both handled the same logic. That's obviously not good practice since that leads to duplicate code.

How would I make my application API centric? I was thinking of having an API controller which handles all the logic and returns a JSON object and a regular controller for the frontend which simply takes the JSON object returned by the API controller and passes it to a view (after, if any, processing). If that's the way to go, how would I retrieve said object? A `GET` request to my own server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing API, than it should be on a separate server to take off load form main web server.
If it is on a same server, why would you send a request to it as you can develop a class that can act as API and call it inside your web controllers.

Later on when you decide to have separate server, just wrap API contoller around that class.

```
<?php
$myApi = new MyApi();
$myApi->setParmas( $paramsArray );
$myApi->doLogic();
echo $myApi->asJson();

// or make API class that can handle one liner
echo MyApi::factory($_GET)->doLogic()->toJson();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your Laravel application an API endpoint and use a frontend framework or some frontend routing and templating libraries to handle the client-side.

Name space the api with `/api` and versions i.e. `/api/v1`

This allows you to easily develop with many different technologies and not have to rewrite your backend, as it is just an API endpoint.

It can then serve your webapp, an iOS app, an Android app, etc. because all it does is handle data, validation, requests, security, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use repositories to get required data, then you may pass it to a `View` to make a webpage, or just print the JSON, for the API, this way you can prevent duplicate code.

```
Route::get('/latest', function () {
    return View::make('latest', Movie::latest());
}
Route::get('/api/latest', function () {
    return json_encode(Movie::latest());
}
```

Check this video for more info about repositories in Laravel: http://vimeo.com/53029232

Answer (score 0):

In larval 5.3 you may want to consider using larval passport which provides a really nice way to consume your own api's from the front end without needing to worry too much about the authentication https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

There is also a nice video on this on laracasts https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13